# Using Json in select option value - errors due to double quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a ajax request which returns a list of options for a select form input.  I have a json for the value of each option to represent an address.  However the double quotes cause an issue and only the first `{` is returned to the back end.

Looking at the value in chrome dev tools I can see that the value recognised by chrome is the first `{` and not the whole json.  How can I get the value of a select to correctly hold a json value.

The option value that appears in the browser is:

```
<option value="{" dept":="" "",="" "orgn":="" "pobx":="" "subb":="" "bnam":="" "aspen",="" "bnum":="" "dpth":="" "thor":="" "knoll="" road",="" "ddlo":="" "dplo":="" "town":="" "",="" "cnty":="" "surrey",="" "pcod":="" "gu9="" 2XZ",="" "ppco":="" "tpco":="" 2ep"}"="">ASPEN</option>
```

The ajax event is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#id_previous2_postcode').change(function () {
    var postcode2 = $(this).val()
    console.log(postcode2)
    $.ajax({
      url: '/users/prior_addresses_ajax/',
      data: {
        'postcode': postcode2
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        options = data.property_choices.map(function (subarray) {
          return '<option value="' + subarray[0] + '">' + subarray[1] + '</option>'
        })
        $('#id_previous2_full_address').html(options)
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I think `JSON.stringify` is better to use

Comment: Can you add the response of `JSON.stringify(data)` so we can see what the data looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `new Option` constructor to avoid string concatenation. This will work for any string value.

```js
const data = {
  property_choices: [
    ['value1', 'text1'],
    ['value2', 'text2'],
    ['value3', 'text3']
  ]
};

const select = document.querySelector('#id_previous2_full_address');

data.property_choices.forEach(subarray => {
  const option = new Option(subarray[1], subarray[0]);
  select.options.add(option);
});
```

```html
<select id="id_previous2_full_address">
  <option>None</option>
</select>
```

You may need to call `JSON.stringify(subarray[0])` if the value is an object and not a string like my example above.

Comment: Thanks this worked and was recognised by the backend properly